# Using 'feign clients' without springboot is possible?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

My framework is spring framework. core version is 4.3.16.RELEASE.
Not using springboot. It's one of the legacy project.

And I wanna know what can I use the feign client without springboot.

Is this possible? and where can I found document about that.

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You can find the documentation on their [Github page](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign).

Feign wasn't integrated with Spring initially. There is another wrapper library called [Spring Cloud OpenFeign](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign), and with it, you can use Feign in Spring Boot & Cloud applications more convenient (eg., you can use Spring's `@RequestMapping` annotation instead of default Feign's `@RequestLine`).